# How do I download the Flash objects/assets from this link?

Tags: flash, adobe

I’m trying to download the objects/assets from this link here: https://media.amc.com/swf/originals/breaking-bad/gale-files_20110911/index.html?v=1.0. I have no knowledge of coding or Flash, so all I’ve done is some google digging.

I’ve tried to view page source, that shows me the .swf file and something that says “flashvars” and config. I’ve managed to download the .swf file but on Adobe Flash when I open it, it gets stuck and a window pops up saying something along the lines of “error: config.xml not found”. Is that the file I need for the assets? For reference the only thing I need from this whole situation is the Notebook pages that pop up when you open the Case File and select Notebook.

What should I do in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"I’ve tried to view page source... The only thing I need from this whole situation is the Notebook pages that pop up when you open the Case File and select Notebook."*

Although viewing page source can help locate files, sometimes you need to also check the `Network` section of your browser's Developer Tools.

Clicking the Notebook shows it requests: [Lab book SWF](https://media.amc.com/swf/originals/breaking-bad/gale-files_20110911/assets/labbook.swf) 
(which can be viewed without any extra files like XML)

Comment: Thank you so so much, that file you linked opens perfectly in Flash without any additional files needed and it’s HD, I’ll be sure to remember Dev Tools and the Network tab on Chrome, I messed around with it just now and I was able to replicate finding the labbook.swf. Thank you again